# Is $((X\times Y)^\prime,\|\cdot\|_{(X\times Y)^\prime})$ isometric isomorph to $(X^\prime\times Y^\prime,\|\cdot\|_{X^\prime}+\|\cdot\|_{Y^\prime})$?

Tags: functional-analysis, normed-spaces, dual-spaces

For $X$ and $Y$ normed vector spaces with product space $(X\times Y,\|\cdot\|_X+\|\cdot\|_Y)$ and continuous dual spaces $X^\prime$ and $Y^\prime$, I know that $((X\times Y)^\prime,\|\cdot\|_{(X\times Y)^\prime})$ is isometric isomorphic to $(X^\prime\times Y^\prime,\max\{\|\cdot\|_{X^\prime},\|\cdot\|_{Y^\prime}\})$ via the isometry
$$J\colon X^\prime\times Y^\prime\to(X\times Y)^\prime,~(J(f,g))(x,y):= f(x)+g(y).$$
Is $J$ also an isometry between $((X\times Y)^\prime,\|\cdot\|_{(X\times Y)^\prime})$ and $(X^\prime\times Y^\prime,\|\cdot\|_{X^\prime}+\|\cdot\|_{Y^\prime})$? I tend to say no, but can't come up with a suitable counterexample because of the structure of the dual norm.

Can there exist some other isometric isomorphism between those two spaces?

Comment: Is it an isometry when $X=Y=\mathbb R$?

Comment: @Kavi Okay, if $X=Y=\mathbb{R}$, then $\|J(f,g)\|_{(X\times Y)^\prime}=\max\{\|f\|_{\mathbb{R}^\prime},\|g\|_{\mathbb{R}^\prime}\}\neq \|f\|_{\mathbb{R}^\prime}+\|g\|_{\mathbb{R}^\prime}$. But is this true for any isomorphism $J$? I need to think about this...

Comment: @Kavi I think I've got it. Whatever isomorphism $J$ I choose, $(J(f,g))(x,y)=\alpha x+\beta y$ where $\alpha,\beta\in\mathbb{R}$. Then I can argue as before, right?

Comment: Well, actually, this boils down to $\|\cdot\|_\infty\leq\|\cdot\|_1\leq n\|\cdot\|_\infty$ not implying an isometric structure between $(\mathbb{R}^2,\|\cdot\|_\infty)$ and $(\mathbb{R}^2,\|\cdot\|_1)$.